# Unable to resolve latest version for pipeline templates: this could be due to inaccessible pipeline or no version is available

Tags: azure-pipelines

#### Context

I'm trying to run a pipeline that consumes [pipeline resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-pipelines-pipeline?view=azure-pipelines). Within this pipeline, I use a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) that reffers to an environment.

```yaml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: ref-pipeline
      source: RefPipeline
```

#### Problem

In the process of work, I encounter two errors:

1. > The environment does not exist or has not been authorized for use.
2. > The pipeline is not valid. Unable to resolve latest version for pipeline build_pipeline_portal. This could be due to inaccessible pipeline or no version is available

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for the above problems are listed in the order as specified in the question:

1. Make sure that in environment's security, user has at least `User` assigned permission
2. Make sure that in environment's security, pipelines that you are referencing to are added to `Pipeline permissions` - [Pipeline permissions link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/security/resources?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this issue and found the solution was to rename all pipelines into format of `all-lower-case-hypen-seperated`.

Ensure `source: RefPipeline` in the triggered pipelines YAML definition aligns with the name of the triggering pipeline as defined on the pipeline page within AZDO console.

i.e. I recommend renaming `RefPipeline` to `ref-pipeline` in AZDO console and in the YAML file for the secondary pipeline.

I also found that the pipeline needed to be manually triggered and the Resource (i.e. the triggering pipeline) in the manual run explicitly defined.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVG0E.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnF3c.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Jcig.png)

This may have been due to the renaming of the pipelines I had done previously, but doing this seems to link the pipelines together successfully.